# Errror with typedef: too few template-parameter-lists

Tags: c++, c++11

I've seen some responses to the too few template-parameter-lists problem in classes but I'm getting a similar error in a header file where the declarations seem to be at the name space level. I'm not at all a C++ guy, but I want to figure out what I need to correct in this file to prevent the following error regarding the two lines after the typedef:

```
too few template-parameter-lists
```

Here's a file experpt

```
#ifndef SH_AUDATA_H
#define SH_AUDATA_H

#include "BinaryIO.h"
#include "AudioData.h"

// AuMuLawAudioData
typedef AudioDataImpl<AuMuLaw,BYTE> AuMuLawAudioData ;
inline BYTE AuMuLawAudioData::readValue (BinaryIO* io) const { return (io->read8()) ; }
inline void AuMuLawAudioData::writeValue (BinaryIO* io, BYTE v) const { io->write8(v) ; }

#endif // ndef SH_AUDATA_H
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your `AudioDataImpl` class specialized for `<AuMuLaw,BYTE>`?

Comment: No way to tell without seeing `AudioDataImpl` declaration/`AudioData.h`

Comment: Excellent question. The code for `AudioDataImpl` is [linked here](http://tny.cz/fc125ac9). It relies on the `AudioData` class declaration which I've [linked here](http://tny.cz/c53ca713). `AudioData` relies on [CvrStgObject.h](http://tny.cz/9e20c334).

Comment: @DudeGuy instead of "helpfully" linking to big walls of code outside SO (making the question useless for future reference), reduce your question to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). See my answer for an example :)

Comment: @sehe. Thanks for the insight. I wasn't sure of what info was necessary, but I should have included more. Do you think I should edit the original question?

Comment: @DudeGuy Always edit the question. Also, reducing the code is always good, if only for your own understanding

Answer (score 3):

You either need to

- indicate your defining a template member using `template<>` (http://ideone.com/ZWYuCd)
- or you should just use the full qualified class name (http://ideone.com/zsmHjG)

Contrast both:

```
template <typename T> struct X
{
    T v;

    void foo();
};

typedef X<int> SomeTypedef;

#if 0
    template<> void SomeTypedef::foo() {
        //
    }
#else
    template <typename T> void X<T>::foo() {
        //
    }
#endif


int main()
{
    SomeTypedef a;
    a.foo();
}
```

Both the approaches to define `foo` will work (change `#if 0` to `#if 1` to "select" the other approach)